# Force security propagation on Active Directory objects

Tags: active-directory

I took over a network where it appears that domain users were added to the domain admins group at some point in the past. This caused every account to block security inheritance in Active Directory. Is there an easy way to force inheritance on all user account objects again?

Comment: are you sure its not an adminsdholder problem?

Comment: here is a link 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/05/07/five-common-questions-about-adminsdholder-and-sdprop.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what the problem is (or was). Domain users were added to domain admins group which caused the adminsdholder thread to disable inheritance on every account. Now that the users are no longer part of the domain admin group, I need to re-eneable inheritance.

Comment: Oh wait...I see what's going on...even if I enable inheritance it's still going to disble it...grrrr..easy fix anyone?

Comment: so you've made sure they are not members of the other protected groups right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read carefully!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817433